# Is Zend Framework standalone or part of PHP environment?

Tags: php, zend-framework, windows-7

Should ZF and PHP have the same path to include in php.ini, or can they be put in separate directories?  This is the include path in my php.ini:

```
;Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZF\library\"
```

I couldn't find any Zend documents that specify which, copying ZF\library to xampp\php\PEAR or the entire ZF directory, or using multiple include paths, is recommended for MVC app production.  Is there a good practice or does it depend more on not having access to a certain part of a server or if you are using  shared hosting, combining PHP and ZF would be the better option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should ZF and PHP have the same path to include in php.ini, or can
>   they be put in separate directories?

It is fine to have multiple directories listed in your php.ini.

> include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZF\library\"

The following would be better:

```
include_path = "C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZF\library\"
```

In other words, you don't need the "." in your path since anything that needs to be included in the current working directory can be included like this "./path/to/file.php".

Furthermore, you will want to use an autoloader but having the autoloader search ".", is more work than is needed.

Finally, I generally have an include path of:

```
include_path = "C:\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

The reason is that since PHPUnit is generally installed via the PEAR installer, I always want that globally available; however, for everything else, I can wait until I have access to a PSR-0 compliant autoloader.

Hope that helps.